# PIcture in Picture

Tags: release-loki, system

Is there a way to use picture in picture feature on elementary os Loki? I want to make a video call using skype with this function.

Comment: Check [this](https://plus.google.com/102383287758197741530/posts/RThhdVzb8hN) . You use it pressing Windows key + D and drawing the area you want with the mouse. Make sure you have skype on fullscreen so that other windows don't overlap :)